# Completeness in exponential families

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The completeness theorem for exponential families says that if the natural parameter space contains a k-dimensional rectangle then (T1, ... , Tk) is complete. The proof can be found in 'Testing Statistical Hypotheses', Lehmann, 1986, page 142. I've included it below so you can read it easily.
[image]
[image]

What happens with the other implication of the theorem? Is there any complete statistic that doesn't contain a k-dimensional rectangle such that it can be used as a counterexample?

Comment: Can you include a picture of the proof of the theorem? Thanks. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the question and included the proof. I've tried to find any counterexample for the other implication but I have no idea how to get to it.